# evaluate $\int^{\infty}_1\frac{\ln(x)}{1+x^2}dx$

Tags: real-analysis, integration

I need to calculate the integral: $$\int^{\infty}_1\frac{\ln(x)}{1+x^2}dx$$

My attempt:

IBP: $u=\ln(x) \Rightarrow du=\frac{1}{x}dx, vdv=\frac{1}{1+x^2}dx \Rightarrow v=\arctan(x)$

So, the integral becomes:

$$\ln(x)\arctan(x)\Big|^{\infty}_1-\int^{\infty}_1\frac{\arctan(x)}{x}dx=\ln(x)\arctan(x)\Big|^{\infty}_1-x+\frac{x^3}{3^2}-\frac{x^5}{5^2}+\frac{x^7}{7^2}-...\Big|^{\infty}_1$$

Since the integral $$\int^{\infty}_1\frac{\arctan(x)}{x}dx=\int^{\infty}_1\sum^{\infty}_{n=0}(-1)^n\frac{x^{2n+1}}{(2n+1)x}dx=\int^{\infty}_1\sum^{\infty}_{n=0}\frac{x^{2n}}{2n+1}dx=\sum^{\infty}_{n=0}(-1)^n\frac{x^{2n+1}}{(2n+1)^2}\Big|^{\infty}_1=x-\frac{x^3}{3^2}+\frac{x^5}{5^2}-\frac{x^7}{7^2}+...\Big|^{\infty}_1$$

Is this correct?

Also, this may help with the integral with lower bound $0$

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JCZFVQ9uFHg

Comment: Why does the lower limit change from $1$ to $0$ and back? And how did $\frac{x^5}{5^2}$ turn into $\frac1{x^5}$? And the typesetting on the lower limits of your sums seem to have gone wrong.

Comment: You can get a vertically centred ellipsis with proper spacing to surrounding binary operators like $+$ and $-$ using `\cdots`.

Comment: You are doing arithmetic with non-convergent integrals, so it does not seem correct.

Comment: @joriki i have edited the typos of integrals, and $\frac{x^5}{5^2}$, but what is wrong with the lower limits of my sums?

Comment: @ThePoorJew: There were two errors; you've corrected one of them in the meantime. The remaining error is that the first sum only has $0$ as a lower limit, which should presumably be $n=0$. And you haven't corrected the typos in the integrals; there's still a lower limit $0$ on one of the intermediate integrals.

Comment: @joriki my apologies, it's a typo. It should be good now

Comment: After IBP, you get something like $\infty - \infty$. The series expansion of $\arctan x$ is also only valid for $x \in (-1,1]$. In any case, this integral is Catalan's constant (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Catalan%27s_constant).

Comment: @Raoul oh yes, i completely forgot about the fact that the series expansion is on $x\in[-1,1]$...

Comment: how is Catalan's constant derived then?

Comment: I'd make the substitution $x=e^t$ before expanding in series.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Convert the limits to $(0,1)$ to have the expansion converging,

$$\begin{align}
&\int^{\infty}_1\frac{\ln x}{1+x^2}dx
=- \int_{0}^1\frac{\ln t }{1+t^2}dt\\
& =-\ln t\arctan t\Big|_0^1+\int^{1}_0\frac{\arctan t}{t}dt \\
&=\int^{1}_0\frac1t (t-\frac{t^3}3 + \frac{t^5}5 - ...)dt 
=(1-\frac{t^3}{3^2}+ \frac{t^5}{5^2}- ...)\bigg|^{1}_0\\
&= 1- \frac1{3^2} + \frac1{5^2}  -\frac1{7^2}  +...
\end{align}$$